# Would this three address Ethereum transaction be possible through Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ether, gas, myetherwallet

I would like to store an amount of Ether in an specific wallet, likely a wallet generated in Geth. From there I would like to send the correct amount of Ether, I suppose in the form of Gas, or converted to match the required fee upon deposit, to MEW address with no Ether in it, but several ERC20 tokens in them. From there I would like the Ether to be used as Gas to fuel the transactions of said tokens to a third address.

The flow of transactions would work as follows.

> ETH Address ---> MEW Address --->ETH(AS GAS(+ERC20TOKEN)---> New ETH Address.

Basically is it at least theoretically possible than I can link together a series of Geth commands to execute this from the command prompt, or develop a smart contract to do so?

(Just to clarify, I'm aware that there are only Ethereum addresses, but am specifying between them using the protocols mainly used to generate, access, or otherwise interact with them, so as to make clearer the flow of transactions desired, and the other of said flow.)

Comment: There's a bit of a misconception here. There was a no such thing as 'geth' address vs MEW address. There's just Ethereum addresses. This doesn't answer your question but it does point out that you have some misconceptions. Maybe some more study will have clarify your question